# How to incorporate sub directories using import glob, os?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to make a program to count all unique files in a directory, I did manage to get it working for just top level folders, how can I also capture subfolder?

```
import glob, os

psm = 0
prt = 0
asm = 0
dft = 0
os.chdir("Z:\TopFolder")

for file in glob.glob("*.asm"):
    asm += 1
print('Assemblies: ', asm)

for file in glob.glob("*.psm"):
    psm += 1
print('Sheet Metal Parts: ', psm)

for file in glob.glob("*.prt"):
    prt += 1
print('Regular Parts: ', prt)

for file in glob.glob("*.dft"):
    dft += 1
print('Drafts: ', dft)

total = psm+prt+asm+dft
print('Total unique files (No .PDF, .CFG or Docs: ', total)
```

Comment: also its better to use `if/else` than to iterate over the list every time. This might work just fine if you have few files in folders but will slow down if you have more files.

Comment: Appreciated! I'm working to get the bones working then to clean it up. I also couldn't get os.walk to function with substructures. How would that be implemented in this program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sketch using dictionaries and `os.walk`.

```
import os

extensions = {
    ".asm": "Assemblies",
    ".dft": "Drafts",
    ".prt": "Regular Parts",
    ".psm": "Sheet Metal Parts",
}
count = {x: 0 for x in extensions.keys()}

for dirname, dirs, files in os.walk(r"Z:\TopFolder"):
    for file in files:
        for ext in count.keys():
            if file.endswith(ext):
                count[ext] += 1

total = 0
for ext in count.keys():
    print("%s: %i" % (extensions[ext], count[ext]))
    total += count[ext]
print("Total:", total)
```